# REAL values (floating-point) comparing issue in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, floating-point

I make a query base on sample database `chinook.db` (https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/) below, but the result is strange.

```sql
-- SQLite version 3.30.1 2019-10-10 20:19:45
select
    Total,
    TotalSaleValue
from invoices
natural join (
    select
        InvoiceId,
        sum(UnitPrice) as TotalSaleValue
    from invoice_items
    group by InvoiceId
)
where Total != TotalSaleValue;

-- Output
Total       TotalSaleValue
----------  --------------
13.86       13.86
13.86       13.86
13.86       13.86
13.86       13.86
13.86       13.86
13.86       13.86
13.86       13.86
13.86       13.86
13.86       13.86
13.86       13.86
...
```

I use `where Total != TotalSaleValue` to filter the unequal values, and I expect to have the empty row.
But, the result shows `Total` and `TotalSaleValue` with the same value?!

`Total` is the value from `invoices` table, and the value of `TotalSaleValue` is calculated from `invoice_items` table which is the sum of the `UnitPrice` of each invoice.

```
-- invoice_items Table
InvoiceLineId  InvoiceId   TrackId     UnitPrice   Quantity
-------------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1              1           2           0.99        1
2              1           4           0.99        1
3              2           6           0.99        1
4              2           8           0.99        1
5              2           10          0.99        1
6              2           12          0.99        1
7              3           16          0.99        1
8              3           20          0.99        1
9              3           24          0.99        1
10             3           28          0.99        1
```

```
-- invoices Table
InvoiceId   ...         CustomerId  Total
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           ...         2           1.98
2           ...         4           3.96
3           ...         8           5.94
4           ...         14          8.91
5           ...         23          13.86
6           ...         37          0.99
7           ...         38          1.98
8           ...         40          1.98
9           ...         42          3.96
10          ...         46          5.94
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my query?

#### Update:

I found that the result would be correct if I cast the `Total` and `TotalSaleValue` to `TEXT` and give the alias name `X` and `Y`.

```sql
select
    cast(Total as text) as X,
    cast(TotalSaleValue as text) as Y
from invoices
natural join (
    select
        InvoiceId,
        sum(UnitPrice) as TotalSaleValue
    from invoice_items
    group by InvoiceId
)
where X != Y;
```

Comment: I bet if you use `printf()` to show more decimal digits, you'll see the numbers aren't exactly the same. Very common issue when comparing floating point numbers. See [Is floating-point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @Shawn I use `printf("%10.20f", Total)` to see the result. The values are exactly the same.

Comment: @Shawn Thank you. I found the answer from your reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the reference from @Shwan

https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/2802074

The result will be correct if I use `abs(Total - TotalSaleValue) > 0.00001` to avoid the floating-point break issue.

```
select
    Total,
    TotalSaleValue
from invoices
natural join (
    select
        InvoiceId,
        sum(UnitPrice) as TotalSaleValue
    from invoice_items
    group by InvoiceId
)
where abs(Total - TotalSaleValue) > 0.00001;
```

### Summary

Instead of using `WHERE x == y`, always use `WHERE abs(x - y) < 0.00001` to compare the REAL (floating-point) values